# Quantum Kernel Machine Learning loss function and the plot of kernel？

Tags: qiskit, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, kernel-methods

When I was doing quantum machine learning, after building the quantum kernel, I drew the graph of the loss function changing with the iteration function and the graph of the quantum kernel, but I couldn't interpret the meaning of the quantum kernel graph (the effect is very unsatisfactory, but I don't know why). and why the loss function fluctuates so much (I'm building on QSVR)
Thanks for your kind answer[image]

Comment: Hi @Mistico013 - could you include more details on how your algorithm is set up, like what dataset and what functions you are calling? Also what exactly do these plots mean (how is "loss" defined, do "iterations" refer to an iterative SVM solver, what does light blue and dark blue mean on the kernel matrix heatmap, etc...?

Comment: It would also help if you could provide some sample code. Right now, your algorithm isn't performing any learning, so the quantum kernel graph is effectively the same from whatever state it was initialized in.